# position: sticky junto com overflow;

Tags: javascript, css, css3

existe uma forma de fazer com que `position: sticky` e `overflow-x: auto` funcionem juntos, sem setar valores de `height`? 
 Nessa estrutura que fiz ao setar `overflow-x: auto` na minha class `.scroll`, meu `position: sticky` da tag `th` para de funcionar, porém ao remover o `overflow` o mesmo funciona normalmente. Pesquisei sobre e achei que só funcionam junto com valor de `height` setado. 
 Existe alguma outra forma de fazer com que as duas propriedades funcionem juntas? Se sim somente com css é possível? ou preciso de uma ajuda com javascript? estou usando Angular7, se precisar de javascript, é possível sem ser com Jquery?

```css
table {
    min-width: 250px;
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #c3ac6c;
}

th {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4.5px;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #efefef;
    overflow: hidden;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even):hover {
    background-color: #ffff99;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    padding: 4.5px;
    text-align: center;
}

tr{
    min-height: 25px;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #ffff99;
}

.fixed{
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    z-index: 3;    
  width: 100%
}

.scroll {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 800px;
  overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="fixed">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>        
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>        
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>        
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
  <table >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>        
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>   <tr>
          <td>1</td> <td>2</td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Cara eu não entendi direito, vc quer isso? https://imgur.com/JDxZvSW ?  Fiquei meio confuso com qual resultado final vc espera...

Comment: Isso mesmo, porem não consigo chegar nesse resultado sem setar `height`, preciso que minha tabela tenha o tamanho de linhas que vier do banco, com tabela da esquerda fixa, e os headers fixos na horizontal e vertical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara mas se vc não que definir um tamanho para sua tabela como vc quer que ela tenha scroll? Se vc não vai definir o tamanho da tabela vc precisa definir a altura de algum elemento que a tabela vai estar dentro, mesmo que seja o `body`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz esse exemplo onde a `div.scroll` tem 100% da altura e da largura do `body`. Usei `max-width` e `max-heigt`, então o *scroll* só vai aparecer se o conteúdo for maior que o *container* pai, se for meno não aparece *scroll*

Aqui eu diminui o número de elementos por causa da limitação de caracteres do Snippet do Stackoverflow, mas vc pode testar ai com mais conteúdo para ver como fica

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    table {
        min-width: 250px;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    thead th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #c3ac6c;
    }

    th {
        border-top: 1px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4.5px;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #efefef;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(even):hover {
        background-color: #ffff99;
    }

    td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        padding: 4.5px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    tr {
        min-height: 25px;
    }

    th:first-child,
    td:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }

    tr:hover {
        background-color: #ffff99;
    }

    .fixed {
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 100%
    }

    .scroll {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="fixed">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>



    </div>

    <script>

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```